# Why do JavaScript functions work this way?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a good grasp of most static typed languages mainly C and C++. But when I went into javascript I noticed something that bummed me out.

I learned to write this function to interact with inner HTML:

```
document.getElementById("SomeHTML").onclick = function(){



    document.getElementById("AnotherHTML").innerHTML = "<p> Joe has a cat </p>";

}
```

That is all fine and well but there is a problem. How am I supposed to reuse this and keep it readable?... coming from a C++, I was always taught to write code in this way:

```
function MyFunc()
{
           document.getElementById("AnotherHTML").innerHTML = "<p> Joe has a cat </p>";
}

document.getElementById("SomeHTML").onclick = MyFunc();
```

The latter code being cleaner (at least to me) and I can reuse the function, but it doesn't work ... I am able to write this way in every programming language yet in javascript it produces an error. I don't know what I am missing, I know its something simple. Can someone please help me understand why I cant write javascript functions in this way? Or if I can please tell me how, because I much prefer the latter than the former. thanx in advance.

Comment: The latter code will work in JavaScript as well

Comment: `.onclick = MyFunc()` is assigning the result of `MyFunc();`. Use `.onclick = MyFunc;` instead. You can also try the TypeScript Playground to see the error https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20MyFunc()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.getElementById(%22AnotherHTML%22).innerHTML%20%3D%20%22%3Cp%3E%20Joe%20has%20a%20cat%20%3C%2Fp%3E%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.getElementById(%22SomeHTML%22).onclick%20%3D%20MyFunc()%3B

Comment: @Slai is right, and ironically the code you propose would not work in C++ too. You have to assign the function to the handler, not the result of its execution (or you have to return a function as a return of your evaluation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck! The latter code will work in JavaScript as well.

Below, I've outlined three different ways you can achieve this using a more familiar syntax.

```js
// The function to call
function MyFunc(){
  alert('Working!');
}

// Option 1 (Link 1)
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", MyFunc);

// Option 2 (Link 2)
document.getElementById("two").onclick = MyFunc;
```

```html
<a href="#" id="one">Link 1</a><br>
<a href="#" id="two">Link 2</a><br>
<a href="#" id="three" onclick="MyFunc()">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: That is a very wierd way to write it but ill take what i can get as it does work and i can resue the function. thanks alot!

Comment: @chree Our of curiosity, what do you think is so weird about that? The syntax `func()` with `()` at the end usually indicates a functioncall. This is true for statically typed languages as well. On the other hand, `foo = bar`, with no parentheses, usually indicates an assignment.

Comment: its because its inside another function instead of being the function itself

Comment: @OptimusCrime he means the original answer before the edit

Comment: The way im used to writing it is just MyFunc(); yet apperently in javascript u write function(){MyFunc()}; which works fine. im not comlaining

Comment: @chree You need to open yourself up to the possibility that Javascript is different from C/C++

Comment: @chree They are different languages, and they do things differently. If they did things the same way, it would be the same language.

Comment: This is a late comment, sorry.. I accept all your points. thats fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not quite reusable, to me I would have used another approach

```js
// Original version
function MyFunc() {
    document.getElementById("AnotherHTML").innerHTML = "<p> Joe has a cat </p>";
}

document.getElementById("SomeHTML").onclick = MyFunc();

// Function Generator
function MyFunc_generator(element, html_content) {
    return function() { 
        element.innerHTML = html_content;
    }
}

myfunc = MyFunc_generator(    
    document.getElementById("AnotherHTML"),
    "<p> Joe has a cat </p>"
}

document.getElementById("SomeHTML").addEventListener("click", myfunc);
```

There are quite some difference in the code.
We can start with comparing the original `MyFunc` function and the `MyFunc_generator` one.

The first does not have a return statement and so the assignment 
`document.getElementById("SomeHTML").onclick = MyFunc();` would assign the value `undefined` the the onclik handler of the html element whose id is "SomeHTML".

The "MyFunc_generator" function is an [Higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), a function that return a function as result of his evaluation.

The execution of the generator function has the result to create a specialized function with real values instead that generic ones.

The assignment in the example would create a function (anonymous) and assign the name `myfunc` to it. That function will be equal to your.

You can change the parameters of the generator to create similar function with different targets, and/or different content.

Obviously the effort in a such simple case will not worth the result but if the strategy you have to describe is quite complex the benefit will increase.

One last note. The assignment of the handler function to the event is different. In javascript the preferred way is with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)